# php json_encode changed behaviour in php 5.4

Tags: php, xml, json

I have the following `xml`:

```
$resultXML=<<<XML

<Mapper ProviderCode="" ProviderName="" SessionID="" Supplier="" ProviderSupplier="">
<ProviderSupplierName/>
</Mapper>

XML;
```

When I issue:

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_string($resultXML);
echo json_encode($sxml);
```

in `PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze15`, I get:

```
"Mapper": {
    "@attributes": {
        "ProviderCode": "",
        "ProviderName": "",
        "SessionID": "",
        "Supplier": "",
        "ProviderSupplier": ""
    },
    "ProviderSupplierName": {}
}
```

while in `PHP Version 5.4.4-14+deb7u8`, I get:

```
"Mapper": {
    "0": {},
    "@attributes": {
        "ProviderCode": "",
        "ProviderName": "",
        "SessionID": "",
        "Supplier": "",
        "ProviderSupplier": ""
    }
}
```

I want to use `PHP Version 5.4.4-14+deb7u8` and get same result as `PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze15`.

Actually this xml is part of a very long xml. When I extract it as in this case, i get similar results on both versions of php.

The full xml can be found at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9zOzk6voXHKQ3N1ZklfVFVITFU/edit?usp=sharing

Another thing I noticed is that if I use the xml as given in link, I get the json as in the second example, but if I use an xml formatter and format the xml, then I get the json in the first example.

Any help?

Comment: The behaviour of `json_encode` did not change. But perhaps that of `simplexml_load_string` did.

Comment: This seems like a classic [X/Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me: regardless of why this is behaving differently in different environments, converting an XML document blindly into JSON like this seems like a rather pointless exercise. What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: "Actually this xml is part of a very long xml. When I extract it as in this case, i get similar results on both version of php." <- So, the example you gave us doesn't actually reproduce the problem? That's not particularly helpful for debugging it.

Comment: @IMSoP I have edited the question and included the full xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need the `<ProviderSupplierName/>` tag to reproduce the issue and, as you already mention, the different output happens when you [reformat the source XML and add white space around it](http://3v4l.org/0CuKY):

```xml
<Hotels>
    <Hotel>
        <Mapper><ProviderSupplierName/></Mapper>
    </Hotel>
</Hotels>
```

```js
{"Hotel":{"Mapper":{"0":{}}}}
```

```xml
<Hotels>
    <Hotel>
        <Mapper>
            <ProviderSupplierName/>
        </Mapper>
    </Hotel>
</Hotels>
```

```js
{"Hotel":{"Mapper":{"ProviderSupplierName":{}}}}
```

To get [coherent pre-PHP/5.4 automated parsing](http://3v4l.org/qaJlU) you can provide the [LIBXML_NOBLANKS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php#constant.libxml-noblanks) flag («Remove blank nodes»):

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_string($resultXML, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
```

*(It's hard to say whether the change is intentional but a vanishing tag name feels like a bug.)*

Comment: Thanks for finding the way to easily reproduce the issue and giving a solution. It does seem like a bug. I will check on https://bugs.php.net/report.php to see if similar issues have been reported and do the necessary.